# How to return to a specific condition in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to run a program that saves words then gives the users 5 different options. I stuck in option 3 since the modifying word works but once I modified one word I would the program to go back to beginning and starts all over again from "while choice != q"
so here is my code:

```
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':

    print ("[1] for to see the existing words")
    print ("[2] for to enter a new word and meaning ")
    print ("[3] to modify the existing meaning")
    print ("[4] to categorize existing words")
    print ("[5] to delete a word and its meaning")
    print ("[quit] in order to quit")
    choice = raw_input("Please select what you want to do ")
    title_bar()

    if choice == '1':
        print Vocab_World
    elif choice == '2':
        ask_word_meanings()
        Save_Vocab_World()
    elif choice == '3':
        for key,value in Vocab_World.items():
            print (key+":means "+value)
        while choice =='3':
            modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify: ")
            Vocab_World[modified_word]=raw_input('What is the new meaning of %s '%modified_word)
            choice != 'q'
    elif choice == '4' :
        categorized_words = raw_input("Please select the words that you want to categorize")
        new_category = raw_input("Please input the new category name ")


    elif choice == 'quit':
        print "Thanks For playing"
```

and now If I ran the program you will see that after I modified the word "ceken" it keeps asking me which word I want to modify where it should start the while choice !='q'  from at least that what I want

```
(venv) C02QMASLG8WN:Python $ python Vocab_test.py 
**************************************************VOCABULARY_WORLD**************************************************
[1] for to see the existing words
[2] for to enter a new word and meaning 
[3] to modify the existing meaning
[4] to categorize existing words
[5] to delete a word and its meaning
[quit] in order to quit
Please select what you want to do 1

**************************************************VOCABULARY_WORLD**************************************************
{'excelent': 'wonderful', 'quit': 'exit', 'ozlem': 'hasret', 'ceken': 'bilir', 'gurbet': 'hasret', 'postpone': 'put_offt'}
[1] for to see the existing words
[2] for to enter a new word and meaning 
[3] to modify the existing meaning
[4] to categorize existing words
[5] to delete a word and its meaning
[quit] in order to quit
Please select what you want to do 3

**************************************************VOCABULARY_WORLD**************************************************
excelent:means wonderful
quit:means exit
ozlem:means hasret
ceken:means bilir
gurbet:means hasret
postpone:means put_offt
which word you would like to modify: ceken
What is the new meaning of ceken bilmez
which word you would like to modify:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while choice =='3':
    modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify: ")
    Vocab_World[modified_word]=raw_input('What is the new meaning of %s '%modified_word)
    choice != 'q'
```

This will loop forever, as `choice` is never modified inside the `while` loop. Also, the `choice != 'q'` statement is not doing anything, as it performs an evaluation (whether `choice` has the value `'q'`) and then discards the result.

Option 1: Remove the while loop, so that it asks for one word to be modified, and then returns to the start. In that case, the above will simple become:

```
modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify: ")
Vocab_World[modified_word]=raw_input('What is the new meaning of %s '%modified_word)
```

Option 2: Keep asking the user for words to modify until they indicate they are finished modifying words. E.g. You could use an empty input to signify that they are done modifying words:

```
while True:
    modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify (leave blank to finish modifying words): ")
    if modified_word:
        Vocab_World[modified_word]=raw_input('What is the new meaning of %s '%modified_word)
    else:
        break
```

Also, the `elif choice == 'quit':` test at the end is looking for the user to enter 'quit', while the outer while loop will exit only when the user enters just 'q', not 'quit'. You need to be consistent there.

Answer (score 0):

Use **break** to come out of while -

```
print ("[1] for to see the existing words")
print ("[2] for to enter a new word and meaning ")
print ("[3] to modify the existing meaning")
print ("[4] to categorize existing words")
print ("[5] to delete a word and its meaning")
print ("[quit] in order to quit")
choice = raw_input("Please select what you want to do ")
title_bar()

if choice == '1':
    print Vocab_World
elif choice == '2':
    ask_word_meanings()
    Save_Vocab_World()
elif choice == '3':
    for key,value in Vocab_World.items():
        print (key+":means "+value)
    while choice =='3':
        modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify: ")
        if modified_word =='q':
            break
        else:
            Vocab_World[modified_word]=raw_input('What is the new meaning of %s '%modified_word)
elif choice == '4' :
    categorized_words = raw_input("Please select the words that you want to categorize")
    new_category = raw_input("Please input the new category name ")


elif choice == 'quit':
    print "Thanks For playing"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to break out of the `while choice =='3'` block. I'm assuming since you have a while block there in the first place, you want it to keep asking for more words until you give it some command to tell it to stop. For a simple hack:

```
while choice =='3':
    modified_word = raw_input("which word you would like to modify: ")
    if modified_word == "done":
        break
```

The answer really just depends on what you're ultimately trying to do. As an aside, given the level of interaction and number of prompts, I'd recommend taking a look at [prompt toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master).